# Datepart function error in Microsoft Dynamics SQL

Tags: sql, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, datepart

I am currently trying to perform a SQL query in Microsoft Dynamics AX2012, to output a year from delivery date by using a DATEPART function.

I have created a class "CustRerportDemo" in the AOT, and while attempting to perform a query, which is to query out only the year from the field "deliverydate" in the table "SalesTable". I encountered an error that prompts:

> Variable Datepart has not been declared

I understood that datepart is a function call in SQL and shouldnt need to be declared. Hence, I am wondering why and how to rectify this issue? I am only just trying to show the year from the delivery date.

Therefore, if the date is 13/06/2016, the resultant query result will just be 2016 or 16.
I have attached the following code. Please help.

```
public void processReport()
{
CustTable custTable;
SalesTable salesTable;

//select all customers
while select * from custTable
{
    //clear the temporary table
    custReportRDPTmp.clear();
    //assign customer account and name
    custReportRDPTmp.CustAccount = custTable.AccountNum;
    custReportRDPTmp.Name = custTable.name();
    //select count of invoiced sales order of customer
    select count(RecId) from salesTable
    where salesTable.CustAccount == custTable.AccountNum
    && salesTable.SalesStatus == SalesStatus::Invoiced;
    custReportRDPTmp.SalesOrderInvoiceCount = int642int(salesTable.RecId);
    //New Column to display PaymentMode
    select PaymMode
    from salesTable
    where salesTable.PaymMode == custTable.PaymMode;
    custReportRDPTmp.Payment = SalesTable.PaymMode;
    //New Column to display SalesAmountTotal by drawing from a different table using a JOIN statement
    select smmSalesAmountTotal
    from salesTable;
    custReportRDPTmp.SalesAmt = salesTable.smmSalesAmountTotal;

    //New Column to display month from delivery date
    select DATEPART("yyyy", DeliveryDate) as year
    // To extract  a single value for year and month from DeliveryDate in SalesTable
    from salesTable

    /* where payment in (select count(payment) from salesTable
     where salesTable.CustAccount == custTable.AccountNum
    &&*/

    //insert in temporary table buffer
    custReportRDPTmp.insert();
}
}
```

Edited code:

```
select firstOnly DeliveryDate
from salesTable
where salesTable.CustAccount == custTable.AccountNum;
//Get Year from date
custReportRDPTmp.DateTimeStamp = year(salesTable.DeliveryDate);
```

Result as shown:

[image: As Seen under the DATETIMESTAMP: REturn value of 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X++ select statement is *not* SQL and thus you should not assume that any or all SQL functions is available in X++; they are not!

There *are* date functions, the one you search is called [year](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa865589.aspx).

It does not belong in the select though:

```
select firstonly DeliveryDate from salesTable;
y = year(salesTable.DeliveryDate);
```

Comment: Will I need to create a table by the variable of "y" to store the field for year? Thanks for your help

Comment: furthermore, wouldn't `firstonly` mean that only the first data in the column be selected?

Comment: You will need a variable (`y` or whatever) to hold the value. You will need a table field only, if you need to group on the value. You can even format the date field in the report to only show the year. The `firstonly` selects one record only, you should do the select you need.

Comment: Yes, 'firstonly' only selects one record, however, I understand it as it will only return one query record from the top stack. How about other records that is being matched with different i.ds?

Comment: Use a `while select salesTable where ...` to select matched orders.

Comment: sorry, I don't really get it

Comment: I advice you to study the X++ language and examples of its use. Explaining `while select` here would be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I have used the following method suggested by you, however returned query values are all 0 in the report. why is that so

Comment: I guess your `DateTimeStamp` is of type `DateTime` instead of `int`. In that case transfer the hole date and do the formatting in SSRS.

Comment: The type is actually in int. Furthermore, if I were to specify the typr as a str for DATETIMSTAMP, I have done this for the following code: 'custReportRDPTmp.DateTimeStamp = int642str(year(salesTable.DeliveryDate)); '

Comment: Change the table to not temporary, then table browse the table.  
I have previously problems with new fields, a restart of the report server might do the trick.